# Adding text box data to url

Tags: jquery, text

I may be missing something basic but I have a text box in html that I want users to add some text to and when they click a button it is added to the url:

e.g.

```
<form id="discount_code" action='' method='get'>
    <input type='text' name='code' id='code' placeholder='Enter a discount code..'></>
    <input type="button" class='small-button' id='useCode' value='Use Code' onClick="parent.location='www.url.com?id=32&code=< TEXT ENTERED HERE >'" />
</form>
```

is there any way I can get this to work with jQuery change event or similar?  I've searched and found a number of similar suggestions but nothing seems to work.  I need it to be passed to the url in a GET format.  It also preferably needs to work in situations where someone pastes the text.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the text in the URL and for the user to remain on the same page? Or for the URL to change and the user to proceed to the new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET will automatically put the parameters in the header.

So, if you change the action of your form to www.url.com like this:

```
<form id="discount_code" action='//www.url.com' method='get'> 
<input type='text' name='code' id='code' placeholder='Enter a discount code..' />         
<input type="button" class='small-button' id='useCode' value='Use Code' /> 
</form>
```

..This should append whatever is put into code into the the URL.  As far as putting id in, you could create a hidden element or another input similar to this:

```
<form id="discount_code" action='//www.url.com' method='get'> 
<input type='text' name='code' id='code' placeholder='Enter a discount code..' /> 
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='23' />        
<input type="button" class='small-button' id='useCode' value='Use Code' /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Half my post was cut off...see the rest for more info.

Comment: you sir, are a star.  I love the simple ideas that just work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You missed the http:// in front of the url. 
When you start a url with www the browser asumes it's relative to the current url.

```
<form id="discount_code" action='' method='get'> 
<input type='text' name='code' id='code' placeholder='Enter a discount code..' />
<input type="button" class='small-button' id='useCode' value='Use Code' onClick="parent.location='http://www.url.com?id=32&code=< TEXT ENTERED HERE >'" /> </form>
```

Comment: sorry, that was due to me removing the actual url.  It does normally have the http

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#useCode').click(function(){
        var code = encodeURI($('#code').val())
        parent.location = 'http://www.url.com?id=32&code=' + code;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#discount_code").submit(function(e){
  var data = $(this).serialize();
  e.preventDefault();

  top.location = 'http://example.com/?code='+data.code;
});
```

Comment: I tried but couldn't quite work out why it isn't working.  What should "form" be replaced with for this to work?  also, should textName be replaced?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url, add textbox value, and then redirect to the new url like this. The page will refresh though.

```
    var url = document.URL;
    window.location = url + $('#textboxID').val();​
```

Comment: what action will cause the refresh?

Comment: the fact that you are redirected to the new url (with the new data) by window.location